# What's the meaning of キドクつかねーぞ?

Tags: phrases

I stumbled on the phrase キドクつかねーぞ in the manga I'm reading. The context is the MC (Male character) is bickering with the FC (Female character) for being too careless. Below is the MC and FC's dialogue in Japanese:

> MC: おい 愛菜(えな)
> 　　これ　朝マンションの下に落ちてたぞ (The item was a wallet.)
>
> FC: え
> 　　ありがとー！
> 　　さがしてたの！
>
> MC: つーかおまえ先行くなよ
> 　　あぶなっかしいんだから
>
> FC: だって今日横倉先輩の朝練の日だったんだもん！
> 　　ファンとしては見なきゃいけないじゃん！
>
> MC: 知るか！
> 　　ポロポロ物おとしていきやがって！
> 　　忘れもんは!?
>
> FC: ない!
>
> MC: スマホもってねーだろ！
>
> Sfx: ぎくっ (I can't determine, to whom is this for but i assume it's from the FC)
>
> MC/FC?:キドクつかねーぞ　(This is written near the balloon of the last sentence of the MC)

And here is how I understand the dialogue in English:

> MC: Have you forgotten anything else!?
>
> FC: None!
>
> MC: You don't have your cellphone, right!
>
> FC/MC?:キドクつかねーぞ

In the last dialog I'm not really certain if the MC/FC is the speaker since I'm not sure of it's meaning.

I've tried to research on Google and arrived at the assumption that maybe this phrase is the same as "既読つかない". I tried to read the content of this site http://appllio.com/line-deja-vu (though it's written in Japanese), but it seems that this phrase is about marking an email as unread. But with that I think it means "Stop reading my thoughts!"

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I guess キドクつかねーぞ means "you can't read messages in Line".

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam Thank you for your reply. Can I ask a related question? Does it mean that when "キドクつかねーぞ" is used it is always in reference to Line messages?

Comment: I think 既読 is also used for other messages like Facebook, Yahoo Mail, etc. I am not sure that キドクつかない is commonly used as the meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

キドク, usually written 既読, means "has been read" (「既」=already, 「読」=read).  つかねー(ぞ) is a colloquial, masculine way of saying つかない(ぞ), which is the negative form of [付]{つ}く.

> it seems that this phrase is about marking an email as unread.

既読が付く means "marked as read." キドクつかねーぞ is 既読がつかないぞ, literally meaning "isn't marked as read".

Here the male character says "The message that I've sent you isn't marked as read" / "The messages that I've been sending you don't get marked as read", implying "You've left your smartphone, right? So you can't read my messages."